# SSAS Attribute relationship behavior in Hierarchy

Tags: ssas

I am using SQL server 2012 with Visual Studio 2015.
(While I am an excellent SSRS developer I am only just getting into SSAS)

I basically want to use the hierarchy as it neatens up the Excel Front end more than anything. At the same time though I want the attributes to behave in the same manner, when in the browser on their own, as they would if they are not in the hierarchy.

I have a customer dimension, for example,  where the PK is an int called ID with a customer ID and Delivery Postcode
The attribute relation ship is set to;

```
ID to Customer ID 
ID to Delivery Post code
```

The full hierarchy displays like this;

**CustomerID Delivery PostCode Order Quantity**

```
1   FY5 3TG 1
2   CH2 1NF 1
3   SK22 4DT 1 
4   L20 6LT 1
5   FY6 8BX 1
6   WA8 7XP 1 
7   L18 3JN 1
8   L12 3HB 1
9   M28 0SX 1
10  BB7 9AZ 1
10  ZZ99 9ZZ 1
9   ZZ99 9ZZ 1
```

If you just pull the delivery post code, from the hierarchy, through it returns;

**Delivery PostCode Order Quantity**

```
FY5 3TG 1
CH2 1NF 1
SK22 4DT 1 
L20 6LT 1
FY6 8BX 1
WA8 7XP 1 
L18 3JN 1
L12 3HB 1
M28 0SX 1
BB7 9AZ 1
ZZ99 9ZZ 1
ZZ99 9ZZ 1
```

I would expect the post codes at the bottom to roll up, eg postcode ZZ99 9ZZ,  (like it would in a normal excel pivot for example),  like the below. It is also worth noting that I have left the attributes visible outside the hierarchy. If use that delivery Postcode attribute it also returns the below;

**Delivery PostCode Order Quantity**

```
FY5 3TG 1
CH2 1NF 1
SK22 4DT 1 
L20 6LT 1
FY6 8BX 1
WA8 7XP 1 
L18 3JN 1
L12 3HB 1
M28 0SX 1
BB7 9AZ 1
ZZ99 9ZZ 2
```

I don't understand why the same attribute is acting differently inside and outside the hierarchy. My only conclusion, which is probably wrong(!), is that the hierarchy itself is forcing the Delivery Postcode attribute to act differently.

Any help would be great.

I basically want to use the hierarchy as it neatens up the Excel Front end more than anything. At the same time though I want the attributes to behave in the same manner, when in the browser on their own, as they would if they are not in the hierarchy.

Comment: Is this multidimensional or tabular? If multidimensional, check that you have the appropriate [key columns](http://bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1887/ssas-understanding-keycolumns-dimension-property). Also, check the [attribute relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176124(v=sql.110).aspx). Is it possible you have something marked as rigid when it should be flexible?

Comment: Its a multidimensional cube with the relationship set to flexible. To be honest I think I am trying to use the hierarchy where its not appropriate, based on how cube has been designed.